# PHP: What is a special buffer?

Tags: php, buffer

Quote from http://php.net/ob_end_clean

> Reasons for failure are first that you called the function without an
>   active buffer or that for some reason a buffer could not be deleted
>   (possible for **special buffer**)

What is this special buffer?

Right now, to clean all buffers, I have code like this

```
while (@ob_end_clean());
```

But if for some reason it should encounter a "special buffer" this would probably make an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manual again http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

I think *special* buffers may refer to buffers created via `ob_start()` with specific parameters like `chunk_size` or `erase`.

**chunk_size**

> If the optional parameter chunk_size is passed, the buffer will be
>   flushed after any output call which causes the buffer's length to
>   equal or exceed chunk_size. The default value 0 means that the output
>   function will only be called when the output buffer is closed.

**erase**

> If the optional parameter erase is set to FALSE, the buffer will not
>   be deleted until the script finishes. This causes that flushing and
>   cleaning functions would issue a notice and return FALSE if called.

Comment: Also ob_etaghandler can't be ended, doing so emits a warning.